# Wordpress Cannot login to Admin Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I log into my website

https://www.raisinghopesa.com/wp-admin

it redirects me to login and I login fine and the admin bar on top shows BUT there is no option for Dashboard, nothing just blank. I have checked the PHPmyadmin and I am an admin.

I tried to access the dashboard directly by going to

https://www.raisinghopesa.com/wp-admin/index.php after logging in and it told me I am not allowed to access this page

Tried:

Renaming plugin folder

renaming theme folder to force default theme

Created new admin user level 10 in PHPmyadmin

changed PHP versions in case of any conflict

Checked my Permissions

Comment: Please share more details. Is this in any way related to programming?

Comment: If the whole page is blank, it might be an error. Try to: enable debugging, disable all plugins ( rename plugins folder ), enable a default theme ( rename the currently active theme )

Comment: @CornelRaiu the site is working normally if you go to it. Only access the admin panel is the issue. I will try this now thank you

Comment: @CornelRaiu renaming the plugin or themes folders still has the issue with access wp-admin. You not allowed to access this page. I have also downloaded a fresh wordpress install and copied over the files (besides wp-content) and still the same issue.

Comment: in MySQL, what is your user level?

Comment: @CornelRaiu my user level is 10. I made a new admin user in PHPmyadmin to see what would happen and still the same issue.

I enabled debugging and got this error showing on the "Not allowed to access" page

Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(D:\vhosts\raisinghopesa.com\httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/https://www.raisinghopesa.com/wp-content/plugins/login-customizer/resources/languages/login-customizer-en_ZA.mo) is not within the allowed path(s): (D:/vhosts/raisinghopesa.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\) in D:\vhosts\raisinghopesa.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\l10n.php on line 748

Comment: @CornelRaiu i renamed the login customizer folder in plugins and the debug error went away. But still not allowed to access

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags. Unless proven otherwise, I assume that phpMyAdmin is not part of your problem

Comment: @NicoHaase hi sir sorry about that from what I am reading up it could be an error in PHPmyadmin area of the database. I do apologize

Comment: There is no such thing as a "PHPmyadmin area of the database"

Comment: the SQL database that controls the wordpress site sir @NicoHaase